# Ansible Jinja2 Indentation of subkey is wrong

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a playbook to configure netplan according to Jinja template file from the variables. The problem is indentation goes shifted extra than it supposed to be for subkeys.

My playbook task is like

```
- name: Configuring Netplan
  template:
    src: config.yaml.j2
    dest: "/some_folder/some_file.yaml"
  when: my_conf != []
```

The variables are like

```
my_conf:
  network:
    ethernets:
      eno1:
        "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].eno1 }}"
      eno2:
        "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].eno2 }}"
      eno3:
        "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].eno3 }}"
      eno4:
        "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].eno4 }}"
    vlans:
      "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].vlans }}"
    version: 2
```

```
servers:
  localhost:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      set-name: eno1
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      addresses:
        - 127.3XX.XXX.XXX
    vlans:
  192.168.XXX.XXX:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.XXX.XXX/XX
    eno2:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.XXX.XXX/XX
    eno3:
      addresses:
        - 127.2XX.XXX.XXX
      gateway4: 127.3XX.XXX.XXX
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 127.4XX.XXX.XXX
          - 127.5XX.XXX.XXX
        search:
          - myserver.com
    eno4:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.XXX.XXX/XX
    vlans:
      eno1.101:
        id: 101
        link: eno1
        addresses:
          - 192.168.XXX.XXX/X
```

Since which eno I configure can change, I created a j2 template like

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
{{ my_conf['network']['ethernets']['eno1']|to_nice_yaml|indent(6, true) }}
    eno2:
{{ my_conf['network']['ethernets']['eno2']|to_nice_yaml|indent(6, true) }}
    eno3:
{{ my_conf['network']['ethernets']['eno3']|to_nice_yaml|indent(6, true) }}
    eno4:
{{ my_conf['network']['ethernets']['eno4']|to_nice_yaml|indent(6, true) }}
{% if my_conf['network']['vlans'] is defined and my_conf['network']['vlans']|d('')|length > 0 %}
  vlans:
{{ my_conf['network']['vlans']|to_nice_yaml|indent(6, true) }}
{% endif %}
  version: {{ my_conf['network']['version']|default('2') }}
```

It fetches the localhost config but It doesn't look like the desired output, it does look like with some empty lines and extra shifted for the sub keys. It's wrong for `macaddress` and `addresses`. Also extra line after every key.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
          macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      set-name: eno1

    eno2:
      dhcp4: true

    eno3:
      dhcp4: true

    eno4:
        addresses:
        - 127.3XX.XXX.XXX

  version: 2
```

Comment: it is always my opinion that using a **text** templating language to generate **structured** text is a source of SO questions; I bet you'd be happier generating the `dict` and then `|to_nice_yaml`-ing the whole dict, which if nothing else would generate less questions

Answer (score 0):

`to_nice_yaml` uses 4 spaces for indentation. Use `to_nice_yaml(indent=2)`.